# Parameterless method signature doesn't match params delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, compiler-errors, parameters

Why doesn't:

```
delegate void MyDelegate(params object[] parameters);
static void ShouldMatch() {}
MyDelegate compilerError = ShouldMatch;
```

Compile?  It seems like it should match just fine.

Comment: I had been misled by another method which did match the delegate: `static void DoesMatch(object param)`.  I thought the param would be the first object, when in fact it is an array of all objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate, `MyDelegate` defines a method that takes an array of objects, but your `ShouldMatch` method does not. Suppose you try to pass any parameters to an instance of your delegate like this:

```
compilerError(someObject, someOtherObject);
```

If the method `compilerError` is bound to does not accept any parameters, what would you expect to happen here?

Try defining your method in a way that matches the delegate signature:

```
delegate void MyDelegate(params object[] parameters);
static void ShouldMatch(params object[] parameters) {}

MyDelegate noCompilerError = ShouldMatch;
```

Or you could try wrapping it in a lambda expression, like this:

```
delegate void MyDelegate(params object[] parameters);
static void ShouldMatch() {}

MyDelegate noCompilerError = (paramArray) => ShouldMatch();
```

Answer (score 0):

`params` is a purely compile-time feature.
Delegate binding ignores it.

Your delegate must match the method's parameters exactly, ignoring `params` & optional parameters.

The spec states this explicitly, in §6.6:

> o    The candidate methods considered are only those methods that are applicable in their normal form (§7.5.3.1), not those applicable only in their expanded form.

§7.5.3.1 says:

> For a function member that includes a parameter array, if the function member is applicable by the above rules, it is said to be applicable in its normal form. If a function member that includes a parameter array is not applicable in its normal form, the function member may instead be applicable in its expanded form: